# Mod Rewrite: How to rewrite URL passing everything to index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I enabled mod_rewrite and checked it with `phpinfo()`.

I placed a .htaccess file with

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and a index.php file at apache root directory (/var/www/html/).

Working URL:

```
http://192.168.56.101/index.php

http://192.168.56.101/index.php/edrgderg
```

Failing (404) URL:

```
http://192.168.56.101/sgghsshgfhfgj
```

Mod_rewrite should form this to `http://192.168.56.101/index.php/sgghsshgfhfgj` , but it doesn't.

I want to redirect each request to `index.php`.

**SOLUTION:**

I had to edit my apache configuration:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

I added:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

As sugested here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: What you want to achieve? It is looking like you want to redirect each request to `index.php`

Comment: Exactly, my actual rewrite is a bit more specific, but this is the (not working, ) tricky part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude existing files/directories from your rewrite rule to avoid looping the rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried your version and a similar one: 

`RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]` 

Both do not work for me.

Comment: There are no other rules. I did enter this URL, but I want `http://192.168.56.101/sgghsshgfhfgj` to be passed to `index.php`

Comment: No, still getting 404.

Comment: ok then verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: Thanks, mod_rewirte wasn't properly enabled. I updated my question.

Comment: ok great to know. You will still need these 2 conditions as I suggested above.